# change css with jquery

Tags: jquery

What is the best way to change the css of an element using jquery? I have a list of elements displayed one per line and I want to display them inline, dynamically.Should I use

```
.css({"properties"})
```

And write a whole bunch of code ? Any other suggestions ? Thanks.

Comment: could you maybe add in what your css looks like? Not too sure what you really want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the styles are going to be static then what you can do is externalize the styles into a stylesheet and use jQuery to add CSS classes to your element.

Answer (score 2):

Select the elements you wish to change with the selector, then use the `.css()` method to change the display property.

```
$('.my-element-class').css('display', 'inline');
```

If you need to change multiple properties at once, using an object property map is easier than repeatedly calling `.css()`.

```
$('.my-element-class').css({ 'display': 'inline', 'marginLeft': '100px' });
```

Note the use of 'marginLeft' rather than 'margin-left', the `css()` operator expects the values to be in camelCase I believe.

Answer (score 0):

You can change/add properties like this:
`element.css("display","inlne");`

Answer (score 0):

You can add new class in your CSS sheet and then simply toggle it on the parent element.
Or use `.css({'display':'inline'})`.

Answer (score 0):

Hi if i understand you want to change all properties? Then i think you can use class, addClass,removeClass for this